# Reactjs include HTML alongside child component in Render method

Tags: reactjs

Trying to achieve the following. Whilst rendering my child components, I need to place a divider (the `<hr />`) between the 4th and 5th Child Components. However, when I use the below code, all that's rendered into the DOM is `[Object object]null`. If I remove the `hr`, it renders perfectly.

```
<div>
    {this.props.items.map(function(c, ind) {
        var hr = ((ind == 3) ? <hr /> : null);
        return <Item id={c.id} /> + hr;
    }.bind(this))}
</div>
```

Comment: I guess I could `.map` the first 4, render the `<hr />` and then `.map` the last 4...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` is for string concatenation, but `<Item>` and `<hr>` are objects. 
The + is calling toString on them, which is why you get `[Object object]null`

You could do as you said and map 4 then HR then the last 4.

Another option would be to use reduce, something like:

```
<div>
    {this.props.items.reduce(function(previous, c, ind) {
        var next = previous.concat(<[Item id={c.id} />]);
        if (ind == 3) { next.push(<hr); }
        return next;
    }.bind(this), [])}
</div>
```